# How do I read through 50+ text files within a zip file?

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to write a function that takes a list as input and determines whether the sequence of the numbers in the list corresponds to the sequence of numbers within many textfiles within a zipfile. Each textfile page contains 2 different numbers. For example, if the user inputs [1, 30, 3] the program should start by reading page 1 to see if the number 30 is on that page. If the number 30 is on that page then the program should read through page 30 to see if the number 3 is present. If the number 3 is present then the sequence is correct and the program should return true, if the sequence is incorrect at any point it should return false. How do I efficiently read through all pages?
(The zipfile module is not permitted)

Comment: you want to open a `zipfile` without using the `zipfile` module?

Comment: It may be possible to read a zip file without using the proper module but that would require manually writing a parser for a zip file and it certainly would not be fast or efficient.

Comment: One can use exec() to use unzip commands to obtain list of files and extract specific file to test sequence.  But `zipfile` is the proper way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I created the following code to illustrate the testSequence method

```
class zipSequence(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.zFN = kwargs['zipfile']
        self.seqList = kwargs['seqList']
        self.accessPageList(**kwargs)
    def accessPageList(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        FIXME: create access to list of pages
        '''
        mx = max(self.seqList)+1
        mxList = range(mx)
        self.pgList = [None for i in mxList] 
        for i in mxList:
            n1= self.seqList[i]
            try: n2 = self.seqList[i+1]
            except: break
            v = str((n1,n2))
            self.pgList[n1] = v
    def page(self, i, **kwargs):
        '''
        FIXME: access page 'i';  either via zipfile or exec
        '''
        return self.pgList[i] 
    def testSequence(self):
        mxList = range(len(self.seqList))                    
        for i in mxList[0:-1]:
            pattern = self.seqList[i+1]
            curPage = self.seqList[i]
            page = self.page(curPage)
            if page.find(str(pattern)) > -1: continue
            print("Page %d does not contain %d" % seq)
            return False
        print("Sequence is valid", self.seqList)
        return True

ts = zipSequence(zipfile = 'dummy.zip', seqList = [1,30,3])
ts.testSequence()
```